# Is there a website that gives you the average price of a hotel over a year?

Tags: online-resources, hotels

I have been searching and I can find any simple website that provides the average price over a year

Comment: I think you mean "show me 365 average daily prices of a hotel", but you could also mean "show me a single price that averages out all of the room prices, over a single year".  Can you clarify which version you mean?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. In case you were not aware, an "average" price is not especially useful for planning a particular trip, much like an "average" airfare is next to useless. A large hotel might charge 10 different prices for the exact same room depending on the terms of the reservation, and might charge a different rate for each of their 100 rooms, and will charge a different rate for specific nights or weekends based on historical patterns of demand. The "average" price might be $150, but there may be nights you can get the room for $100 and others where nothing is available for under $200.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But average price is useful if you want to compare beteween hotels. I hotel A has an average price higher than hotel B, you can say that hotel A is expensier than hotel B

Comment: @Carles No, because for your travel patterns, you might always be able to get a room at hotel A for cheaper than hotel B, much like I have only flown Southwest Airlines once in my entire life because I have always been able to get a lower fare on American or United. If you're asking about getting industry data, then this isn't really a practical problem that you face as an individual traveler, and would not be on-topic here; you'd probably have to purchase that information from a business intelligence company or ask the local hoteliers association for sources.

Comment: I can´t pay for that data. I just want it fot my own website. I want to introduce the average price of the hotels I write about.

Comment: As @choster has pointed out there can be many prices for the same rooms, but there are lots many different types of rooms. You would then need to decide how to use the prices of all types of rooms: average of the various prices (so if there's one $100/night standard room rate and one $1000/night super-mega-suite rate, the average is $550/night), weighted average based on the number of rooms of each type (you would then need this info). It probably makes more sense to use the average of the lowest price for any night, but advance purchase rules make this complex...

Comment: @Carles Hotel review sites are typically organized by service level or service quality, not price. In the U.S., a common system is to assign [one to five stars](https://www.smartertravel.com/hotel-star-ratings-what-do-they-mean/) (although exactly what qualifies a hotel for one category or another at the boundaries varies somewhat by publisher or reviewer). Hotel loyalty programs will also split up their properties by category. Price correlates broadly with service level, much as airfares correlate very broadly with distance, but this is not a reliable guide.

Answer (score 3):

It is not really possible to define a useful 'average', as the same rooms are offered for the same night for very different rates, depending on where you book, when you book, what options you chose (cancelable or not, etc.), and how you pay.
Some of these options are used more than others, and only the hotel knows which ones were used how often; they have however a strong interest not to publish this information, as it would result in people learning how to book the cheapest rates only.

So you can define many different ways of calculating your 'average', but for the majority of users it will be meaningless and/or misleading, as your assumptions would not apply to them.

Answer (score 0):

Online rooms booking systems falls under the technique called "obfuscated price". So the price depends on many different factors. All of this is done to make an item not comparable to another. Thanks to that users cannot take advantage of some "price collector" which just simply give you cheapest price of that item.

And because of that you cannot have average price of a hotel over a year simply because there is no such thing as price.

The same "obfuscated price" technique is used in many other areas, e.g. flight prices, bank account fees, new automobile prices etc.

Comment: Hotels do have a base price for a room. It's called the "rack rate" in the trade and is shown on their website. It is more relevant than airline's full fare because it is a reasonable price and people do book it. Certain discounts, such as corporate rates or AAA rates are often set at a fixed percentage off the rack rate.

Comment: While the question uses word "hotel" I think he also wants to include beings like booking.com's apartments, flats etc. to be in the answer - and those prices vary in time and based on site provides it.